# App engine in manual scaling mode does not complete long async function

Tags: node.js, express, google-app-engine

I need to run the scanSources script for a few hours, but the app engine instance keeps restarting and sending /_ah/stop and /_ah/start, not finishing the job. It is in standard mode. It does not log any error and it's working on local server.

It's not clear from docs if the long-running function needs to be put inside the /_ah/start handler or if it can be in another endpoint's handler. Neither of these two ways work for me though.

app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs10
instance_class: B2
manual_scaling:
    instances: 1
```

server.ts

```
import * as express from "express";
import * as cors from "cors";
import { urlencoded, json } from "body-parser";
import { join } from "path";
import "isomorphic-fetch";
import { scanSources } from "./scan-sources";

const app = express()
    .use(urlencoded({ extended: false }))
    .use(json());

app.options("*", cors());

app.get("/", (_req, res) => {
    res.send("Service running");
});

app.get("/_ah/start", (_req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send();
});

let scanRunning = false;

app.post("/scan", cors(), async (req, res) => {
    if (scanRunning) {
        res.status(503).send("Scan already in progress.");
        return;
    }

    req.setTimeout(27600000); // 8 hrs (free daily limit)
    res.setTimeout(27600000); // 8 hrs (free daily limit)

    scanRunning = true;

    try {
        await scanSources();
    } catch (e) {
        scanRunning = false;
        console.error(e);
        res.status(500).send(e.toString());
    }

    scanRunning = false;
    res.status(200).send("Scan finished.");
});

// Listen to the App Engine-specified port, or 8080 otherwise
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}...`);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out at the end, it was due to exceeding memory limit of given app engine instance, which failed silently and kept restarting itself.